# Create a Radio Button group using standard buttons

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, syncfusion, radio-group

The idea here is simple, I've got 2 or more buttons and want to have them act like Radio Buttons. So only one can be checked at any time, and when one is checked the others must uncheck themselves. I'm using MVVM so don't want to go down the route of code behind although it would have been easier for this.

Here is the XAML I've tried which locks up due to the buttons referencing each other.

```
    <Label Text="Group Header Sorting" TextColor="{DynamicResource InverseTextColor}"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
        <buttons:SfButton x:Name="GroupHeaderSortAscButton" Text="Ascending" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="90" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortDescButton}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={converters:InverseBoolConverter}}">
        </buttons:SfButton>

        <buttons:SfButton x:Name="GroupHeaderSortDescButton" Text="Descending" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="90" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortAscButton}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={converters:InverseBoolConverter}}">
        </buttons:SfButton>
    </StackLayout>
```

I've also tried Data Triggers with more success but its still not perfect as it requires the unselected button pressed twice before it starts work.

```
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
            <buttons:SfButton x:Name="GroupHeaderSortAscButton" Text="Ascending" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="90" IsChecked="False">
                <buttons:SfButton.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="buttons:SfButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortDescButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="buttons:SfButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortDescButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </buttons:SfButton.Triggers>
            </buttons:SfButton>

            <buttons:SfButton x:Name="GroupHeaderSortDescButton" Text="Descending" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="90" IsChecked="True">
                <buttons:SfButton.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="buttons:SfButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortAscButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="buttons:SfButton" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference GroupHeaderSortAscButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </buttons:SfButton.Triggers>
            </buttons:SfButton>
        </StackLayout>
```

I'm aware that from XF 4.6 they introduced the RadioButton control, I've tried this and its buggy and according to comments on Git Hub it will have major changes in XF 5, so I don't want to implement this experimental version.

This is the look I'm after:

[image]

Comment: if you are already using SF controls why don't you use their RadioButton?

Comment: Yes I could do but I'm trying to achieve a different style than the usual little circle you get with the radio. I've updated my post to show the design.

Comment: that is a segmented control, not a radio button - SF also has one, and there are a variety of open source options  too

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that control, I'll have a look but it seems though I could use that. I'll still leave open this question as I'd like to see the answer.

Comment: Why dont you try to handle that programmatically in the setter part of binding context of buttons. On click of one button, change status of another buttons. Just couples of lines of code & you get what you want

Comment: @Blu, I'd thought of this but since I'm recently new to Xamarin and MVVM I may have overlooked something. When handling the click of the button, only the instance of that button is passed to the handler and therefore its not possible to set the state of the other buttons or other controls. I know I could find the other controls through the binding context but doesn't this then make the page model dependant on the UI and I thought this was the thing to avoid. I know not everything is achievable in XAML but I try to keep all my UI logic there.

Comment: you don't need to pass instance of the button in MVVM, just bind the buttons n you can access anything in View Model n make them work according to your way

Comment: When using a click handler the the instance of the button is passed as the sender as an object. If I were to use bindings then I'd need a different binding for each one the buttons, its gets messy real quick with a decent amount of buttons. I would rather do this in the XAML using techniques available such as triggers or behaviours.

Comment: Check this out 
https://github.com/UdaraAlwis/XFSegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

We have achieved your requirement by using Syncfusion SfButton. To make it as toggle type, need to set the IsCheckable property as True. Then only it will update the IsChecked property properly. To maintain the single selection, we have extended the SfButton by including the GroupKey internal with further validation.

[CustomRadioButton](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CustomRadioButton-1366750151.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to do this using standard buttons and XAML and avoid 3rd party controls, nothing more nothing less.

I ended up using Syncfusion's SfSegmentedControl which works rather well, but this is a paid for, 3rd party control.